# Elasticsearch Date Histogram with time zone and extended bounds

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

In Elasticsearch 2.x I do a date histogram aggregation and I need to set both the `time_zone` and the `extended_bounds` options:

```
...
"date_histogram": {
  "interval": "1d",
  "field": "time",
  "min_doc_count": 0,
  "format": "epoch_millis",
  "time_zone": "Europe/Rome",
  "extended_bounds": {
    "min": "1496268000000",
    "max": "1498859999999"
  }
}
...
```

It returns the error `failed to parse date field [1496268000000] with format [epoch_millis]`, but it doesn't make sense to me because *that value is actually in milliseconds*:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parse_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse date field [1496268000000] with format [epoch_millis]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "[...]",
        "node": "[...]",
        "reason": {
          "type": "parse_exception",
          "reason": "failed to parse date field [1496268000000] with format [epoch_millis]",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "Parse failure at index [0] of [1496268000000]"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

I am actually using Grafana and trying to find a workaround for [this problem](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/6222).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem: `min` and `max` of the extended bounds must be numbers, not strings:

```
"extended_bounds": {
  "min": 1496268000000,
  "max": 1498859999999
}
```

As said, I am using Grafana, so the problem comes from there. [This pull request](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/pull/8395/commits/db63de681099cfce63e2eeca0be08915527d1ddd) fixes the problem (see changes to `datasource.js`).